Compute the differential of a group action
Consider the map
$$\phi: \mathbb{R}^*\to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2)$$
defined as
$$ t\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & t^2 
\end{pmatrix},$$
where by $\mathbb{P}^2$ I mean the real projective plane.
I would like to compute the differential of this map, i.e. the map $$d\phi_e: \mathbb{R}\to \text{Lie}_e(\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^2)).$$
However, I'm a bit embarassed because I don't know how to proceed.
I have tried to look online, but without success. Any help would be very much appreciated!

It may depend a little bit on what sort of automorphisms you're considering here, but can you at least write down the differential for a map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n$ given by polynomials? If you can, think about how that gets reflected in this situation here.

The difficulty here is that $Aut(P^2)$ is not $GL(3)$, which is an open set in $R^9$, but $PGL(3) = GL(3)/  Diag $.
However, $PGL(3)$ is  isomorphic to $Sl(3)$ the set of matrices of $det=1$.
For your computation, first you write your map with value in $SL(3)$ as $t\to Diag ({1\over t }, 1, t)$, and then use the ordinary differential.
For instance the derivative at $t=1$ is the matrix $Diag (-1,0,1)$.
